# Android Studio: Could not find support-annotations.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin, build-error

I've come across an odd prolem with Android Studio.

I have 3 projects, 2 of which build and run perfectly.  The third however, comes up with this error:

[image]

SDK manager looks OK:

[image]

Now, I have 2 other proejcts which use the same jar file and they build/run OK.

Also I'm not sure about the path in which it's looking:

> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations-25.3.1-25.3.1,jar

Seems a little odd - what is the 'support\support-annotations-25.3.1-25.3.1,jar' ?

Should the path not just be:

> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support

Also, the annotations file *is* present as you can see here:

[image]

I've compared my build.gradle file to my other (working) projects and there doesn't seem to be anything amiss there.

I've also tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Invalidating Cache and restarting Android Studio

I'm wondering - is there anywhere I can change the path in which Android Studio looks or anything else I can do to get rid of this so I can build my project?

Comment: Could it have to do with the `,jar` instead of `.jar`? Can you fix that in your grade buildfile? Unfortunately, I can't see your images as they are blocked on my domain, so I can't tell if that was just a typo in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but ...

I hit exactly the same problem. I had accidentally corrupted my sdk Support Repository. The following steps fixed it:

Go to the SDK manager, click the "SDK Tools" tab. If the check-mark for "Support Repository" is selected, unselect it and click OK. This will delete all of the files in the repository. Then recheck the check-mark, click GO and reinstall the repository.

This fixed my problem. (BTW, running on Ubuntu, not Windows, but the cause of the problem should be the same)

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

1. in `build.gradle` change `supportLibVersion` to `26.0.0`
2. in `app/build.gradle` use:
   `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"`
3. `cd android`
4. `./gradlew clean`
5. `./gradlew assembleRelease`